# Full Ajax PHP MVC Framework

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, frameworks

I want to create a website. I want to use Ajax for every hyperlink and form. I wanted to use jquery but it is hard to create a general code for every link. I want to know if there is any PHP MVC Framewrok which works with ajax?
thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Kenan, There wasn't in december but now there is [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/). It's open source too.

The way how it works is you put a "View" on your "Page" and then can manipulate with it through javascript. So here is example:

```
$view=$page->add('LoremIpsum');
$button=$page->add('Button')->setLabel('Reload Ipsum');

$button->js('click', $view->js()->reload());
```

Clicking button would use AJAX to reload the section of the page.

Please comment and let me know what if this is what you were looking for. As a contributor i'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

Currently they're no "full" ajax mvc's for PHP - BUT:

Check out atk-framework.com, xisc.com or cakephp.org.

Since they're frameworks, the interfaces you will be using for the application can be implemented **onto** the platform; you'll be able to use the MVC-framework as platform for a self-written wrapper you put onto it..

```
[ [FRAMEWORK] <------> [CONTROL] <------> [VIEW] ] <------> [APPLICATION]
```

If you implement it like that, the application uses a second layer which is managed by the mvc and requestable via an internal API.

Might seem complicated, but well, the only and to me most logical solution :)